# Get social media data to make analytics tool

Tags: facebook, analytics, data-mining, data-analysis, social-media

I'm really new in data analytics. I want to do simple research about social media mining.So I want to get data from social media like facebook, twitter or instagram. The result of this research is to get trends of keyword by post, or comment or hashtag. Is there someone help me where I can get the raw data or if it's impossible can you explain why? Thank you

Comment: you need to check out the api docs of those platforms, this is quite broad for stackoverflow, i am afraid. btw, scraping is not allowed, at least not on facebook - so you must use the api. if there is no way with the api, dont do it :)

Comment: Thank you for response @luschn But, I really curious how about the existing analytic social media tool? Where they can get the data from?

Answer (score -2):

Any social media tool can be used to gather information from social media.

The ability to acquire and find meaning in data gathered from social media platforms to support business decisions is known as social media analytics. additionally has the capacity to collect and understand data from social media platforms in order to assist business decisions and assess the efficacy of activities implemented as a result of those decisions.

Comment: Hi Mani. This answer is not helpful because it is too broad. andyrandy has already answered the OP in his comment that the OP's question is too broad and cannot be easily answered.